# Mongoose - FindOneAndUpdate - Type Error

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i am having troubles implementing a findOneAndUpdate query.

```
//UserController

UserDAO                                                                                                       
  ['findOneAndUpdate'](userId, {'passwordToken': passwordToken, 'resetPasswordExpires': resetPasswordExpires})
  .then( (user) => {                                                                                          
    return MailController.forgotPasswordMail(user, hostUrl);                                                  
  })                                                                                                          
  .then( (updated) => {                                                                                       
    return res.status(200).json(updated);                                                                     
  })                                                                                                          
  .catch(error => {                                                                                           
    return res.status(400).json(error);                                                                       
  });                                                                                                         

//UserDAO

userSchema.static('findOneAndUpdate', (userId, query) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!_.isObject(query)) {
      return reject(new TypeError('query is not a valid Object.'));
    }

    User
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id: userId},
        query,
        {upsert: true}
      )
      .exec((err, updated) => {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(updated);
    });
  });
});
```

These are the two methods on my userController and on my userDAO. Once i execute them, it logs out a "findOneAndUpdate.exec is not a method". 
The weird things is that i am returning moongose methods like this way.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Once i finished writing the question i figured out whats was the problem. The function name "findOneAndUpdate" was crashing with findOneAndUpdate original mongoose function. I change function name and i solved the problem!